# How to run an url within a php loop

Tags: php

Suppose I have a php loop as follows:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){    
  $phones = $row['phone'];
  $text   = $row['message']; 
  $url = 'http://abcwebsite.com/user.php? '&mobileno=' . $phones . '&message=' . $text;
}
```

Is that how to run the url inside the loop until the loop is completed?

Comment: What do you mean, run the url? Try `file_get_contents($url);` ?

Comment: Do you know that your code will not work in PHP 7 (future version of PHP) and that `mysql_*` functions are deprecated since a long time ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use array to collect all Urls:

like : $urls=array();

Can use $url inside Loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
    $i = 0;
    $url = array();
      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){    
            $phones = $row['phone'];
            $text   = $row['message']; 
            $url[$i] = 'http://abcwebsite.com/user.php? '&mobileno=' . $phones . '&message=' . $text;
            $i++;
    }
```

And after that you can use array `$url`, which contain all urls.

Comment: but how to execute the url..i used header() function but it works only if there is only one row fetched.